# PHP iframe not passing variables and IP not correct

Tags: php, variables, session, ip-address

I have a PHP page with an iframe in it and sessions.
In both files, the one loaded by iframe and the ones hosting it, i have the follow:

```
session_start();
```

However, when the page open, the content inside the iframe does not have any sessions variables setted, and it shows the server IP instead of the client IP.

So having it hosted on localhost and printing this:

```
echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

Inside the iframe, it returns:

```
::1
```

As IP address and not mines.

Suggestions? Anyone faced this issue?

Comment: ... if it's a local environment won't both the server **and** client be `::1` ?

Comment: Yes but it should print 127.0.0.1. on the host (not iframe) it does print 127.0.0.1 and not ::1

Comment: `::1` **is** `127.0.0.1` - it's the IPv6 version of the localhost loopback.

Comment: But why it returns different values then? by host 127.0.0.1 and iframe ::1 and also, why session variables does not work inside the iframe?

Comment: do you have any proxy setup on server? what is the output of print_r($_SERVER); ?

Comment: They're **not** different values - just different ways of writing the same thing effectively; couldn't really say why the page is returning the IPv4 version while the iFrame is returning the IPv6 version though... [more information here](https://superuser.com/questions/414050/why-is-there-a-difference-between-ping-localhost-and-ping-local-ip-address)

Comment: I don't have any proxy up, it's a WAMP server running on localhost. The following you given me prints a content way too long to paste there

Comment: Well, i solved by passing the session variables as a GET to the iframe, even tho this is not ideal and peoples can actually alterate those variables, but only way to make it work apparently